# Monodevelop VB.NET PRoject

Tags: monodevelop

Upon creating a brand spankin new project in Monodevelop 5.10 on Ubuntu 14.04 I get the follow in error

Project does not support framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'

I have read a couple posts saying I simply just have to change the target framework in preferences under load/save I cannot find the option to change this, I have been through the menu quite a few times now with several new test projects. I found another couple solutions that say I can just change the solution file (something I have had to do on windows before) and this only sorta worked since non of the packages would load correctly and were throwing errors.

Things I have tried.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623964/new-default-vb-net-project-immediately-gives-an-error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960212/cant-set-net-runtime-in-monodevelop-on-windows

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484121/xamarin-studio-gives-error-on-new-project

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28329/error-while-trying-to-load-empty-vb-net-project

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/644477/monodevelop-net-framework-4-change-error.html

Anyone got an answer? I would be delighted. Sorry its been a long night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I changed the 4.5 in the TargetFramework in the *.vbproj file to 4.0 via a text editor.

You can get to the .vbproj file through terminal, just open in a text editor and make the change. After you reload your solution it should work.